# Printing backslash from a luacode* environment

Tags: symbols, luatex

My first attempt with LuaLaTex gave me some headache, trying to generate LaTex code from within LuaLaTex. This required me to print the backslash (to get a LaTeX control sequence).. I think I have found a solution now, but maybe this could also be of interest to others, so I try to post it here as question anyway..

(See also the following questions [Printing LaTeX code in LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16019/printing-latex-code-in-luatex) and [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex))

From the `luacode` package documentation, page 2 it says:

> The variant luacode* goes further and makes even backslash a normal
>   character

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
  tex.sprint("\");
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with `lualatex` gives the error

```
! LuaTeX error <\directlua >:1: unfinished string near '"");'.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
```

Then I thought I just have to add another backslash to escape the first:

```
tex.sprint("\\");
```

But now I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that there are 3 interpretation stages involved.

- First macro expansion (this is avoided in my example due to the `luacode*` environment)
- Then Lua interprets the resulting string, where a backslash is an escape character
- At last LaTex again interprets what Lua has printed..

I had forgotten the last stage.. So the solution is:

```
tex.sprint("$\\backslash$");
```

or

```
tex.sprint("\\textbackslash");
```

Comment: Or `tex.sprint("\\verb+\\+")` depending on the style of backslash you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a **real** backslash, you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} 

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
  tex.print(-2, "\\");
\end{luacode*}

\end{document}
```

In LuaTeX Reference:

> ```
> tex.print(<number> n, <string> s, ...)
> ```
>
> If `n` is −2, the resulting catcodes are the result of `\the\toks`: all category codes are 12 (other) except for the space character, that has category code 10 (space).